# Catch Html5 video src on click play button

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

My goal is to catch Html5 video src when i click on play button of that html5 video frame.How it possible in jquery?

```
<video src="video.ogv">
 video not supported
</video>

<script>
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
 video.onended = function(e) {
  /*Do things here!*/
};
```

```
$('video source').each(function(num,val){
console.log($(this).attr('src'));        // i am not getting this..
strSrc = $(this).attr('src'); 
strPath = strSrc.substring(0, strSrc.lastIndexOf('/'));
strExtenion = strSrc.substring(strSrc.lastIndexOf('.'));
$(this).attr('src', strPath + "/" + "newFileName" + strExtenion );
alert($(this).attr('src'));
```

})

Comment: for this you have to create custom button and get $('video').attr('src'); onclick . you can't make changes on embedded button.

Comment: @AshishMishra can you show me a example ?

Comment: @AshishMishra for example a video in vimeo http://vimeo.com/m/102513133, i press play button then i want to catch the source only for html5 videos.

Comment: nope you can not play the videos that are on another server..like youtube,or vimeo

Comment: @AshishMishra I don't want to play i want to grab that video src using jquery , when i hit the play button on the html5 video then the jquery fetch the src of the playing video.

Comment: please check out my updated answer,may it contain solution .

Comment: No its not working :( @AshishMishra

Comment: look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/yxkbfLr9/

Comment: @AshishMishra just updated

Comment: @AshishMishra Yup that's it but need on play button click

Comment: Its, not possible ,its only a trick to get that src of iframe ,its impossible to get click inside iframe if its not in same domain.

Answer (score 0):

**Something  like** :

```
   <video id='vids' src="video.ogv">
       video not supported
   </video>

   <input id='plyvid' type='button'  />

 <script>
$('#plyvid').click(function(){
 var vid = $('#vids');
 vid.get(0).play();
  var vidSrc =  vid.attr('src'); //Here you get the SRC

 });
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  video.onended = function(e) {

  alert($(video).attr('src')) ;// I am not tested this ..may it works for you.

  };
    </script>
```

Comment: I want to grab that video src using jquery dynamically from other html5 video streaming website not in my website, when i hit the play button on the html5 video then the jquery fetch the src of the playing video. –

Comment: Its not possible to get " onended event " of the video that playing on another website.

Comment: So then whats the solution?

Comment: put your actual  code! with the url, html,js you used.